nuget package manager now want to install transitive package by default?

I want to update a few nuget package and I notice that it now want to install the transitive package by default, show a simple example above
This is new to me, is there a way to return to the old way of just installing the package where the nuget is used?
I dont want to update dozen of csproj with dependency for no reason.
Where is the change log for this behavior?

relevant link to an ongoing discussion https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13940 https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13893

Looks like martinrrm has requested a pull request Don't select transitive packages in Updates tab that will fix the issue.
